# How to change the angular material mat stepper label color?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am currently trying to apply the mat stepper functionality in my application i am going through the example 
from material.angular.io i am trying to apply similarly as shown in the example,

https://stackblitz.com/angular/vmqlalbjanq?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.html

here in this example there are 3 labels 1) Fill out your name 2) Fill out your address and 3) done

in each labels there are inputs like in Fill out your name label you have to fill **last name** and **First name** which
is required and if you do not fill the input it appears in red color. Now i want the label to also appear in red color
if i do not fill the input can someone tell me how to do it.

Comment: you need to override default style of material stepper in style.css file. please check answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make your step label become red when input is not valid you should change your label to

```
  <ng-template matStepLabel>
    <span [ngStyle]="{'color': isNameValid() ? 'black' : 'red'}">Fill out your name</span>
  </ng-template>
```

and add method in the controller

```
   isNameValid() {
     return this.firstFormGroup.pristine || this.firstFormGroup.valid;
```

}

Working example:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/vmqlalbjanq?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.html

Answer (score 3):

To change the style of Material stepper you need to override the default style of material stepper like below

Add below style in your **style.css** file

```
.basic-container .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected {
  background-color: #6cb73a;
  color: #fff;
}

.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon {
    background-color: rgba(167, 35, 35, 0.54);
    color: #fff;
}
```

[**Forked solution on stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnbbjc?file=styles.css)

Hope this help!

Comment: also set   `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your ts code if your are writing component specific class

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ng-template** to display the label:

```
<ng-template matStepLabel>
    <div class="stepper-label"> Name of the label </div>
</ng-template>
```

Now in your css file use the "stepper-label" to add styling:

```
.stepper-label {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit stepper provider in stepper-overview-example component.

```
import {STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';

@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['stepper-overview-example.css'],
   providers: [{
    provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {showError: true}
  }]
})
```

and if you want to show some error massage, use `errorMessage` attribute as input for `mat-step`

```
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" errorMessage="Name is required.">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
```

Comment: this is not working for me. do you have to provide this object in the root module as well, instead, or not at all? this is the example from the official docs but it is not working for me. I am getting a red form but the error message is not showing.